# How to Remove Dataframes from a List That Have Only 1 Row in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes, and many have only 1 row which is causing issues for ggplot. How exactly can I automate removing these dataframes?

Answer (score 4):

We can use `Filter` from `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) nrow(x) > 1, lst)
```

---

Or with `sapply`

```
lst[sapply(lst, nrow) > 1]
```

---

Or with `keep` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
keep(lst, ~ nrow(.x) > 1)
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(data.frame(col1 = 1, col2 = 2), data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10))
```